# Test cases for Django Rest Framework; struggling to get a correct response

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

**Update**: **Solved my own problem**: I've learnt that Django creates its own test database, and as such, it needs to be populated with data. Ran my importer in my test cases and it all worked. So, if you're also wondering why you're tests don't work, check that you've got some data in the test db!
**End Update**

I am writing tests for my Django Rest Framework API but I am struggling to get my code to return a 200 OK. At the moment, my test case continually returns a 404 Not Found.

I'm in the early stages of writing tests, and have a lot to learn. I'm currently following https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

I'm trying to test an endpoint at the following URL

```py
# Not shown here, is that all URLs here will be prepended with /api/v1
    path('case/<int:pk>/', EntireCaseView.as_view(), name='case'),
```

I have an object in my database with an ID (primary key) of 1. I can successful query the API by going to http://localhost:8000/api/v1/case/1/

I receive a valid JSON response (Trampe is a rabbit)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "total_points": 5000,
    "passing_points": 3700,
    "budget": 5000,
    "description": "Saving Trampe from Trauma",
    "name": "Trampe",
    "signalment": "8yr, intact male, mixed breed.",
    "problem": "Respiratory difficulty",
    "image": {
        "id": 1,
        "file": "http://localhost:8000/media/images/trampe.jpg",
        "description": "A lovely picture of Trampe"
    },
```

My API requires authentication, and as such I am providing authentication in my test case.

```py
class CaseTests(APITestCase):

    def test_status_code(self):
        """
        ensure that case/1 returns 200 OK
        """
        # Create a test user
        test_user = User(username='jim', password='monkey123', email='jim@jim.com')
        test_user.save()

        # build a factory and get our user Jim
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        user = User.objects.get(username='jim')

        # Get our view to test and the url, too
        view = EntireCaseView.as_view()
        url = reverse('case', kwargs={'pk': '1'})
        print(url.__str__())

        # Make an authenticated request to the view...
        request = factory.get(url)
        print(request.get_full_path())
        force_authenticate(request, user=user)

        response = view(request, "1")
        print(response.data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Of interest here (at least to me) are the lines
`url = reverse('case', kwargs={'pk': '1'})`
and
`response = view(request, "1")`

If I leave out either the `kwargs` argument in `url =r everse('case', kwargs={'pk': '1'})` or the `"1"` in `response = view(request, "1")` I will receive an error saying that the get() method requires 2 positional arguments but only given.

Here is the signature of the get() method in my view.

```py
class EntireCaseView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
```

If I run my test, Django reports that it fails because of a 404.

```
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

What I am trying to work out is why this is the case. Printing `print(url.__str__())` outputs `/api/v1/case/1/` as does `print(request.get_full_path())`

So in summary, I am trying to understand why I'm receiving this 404, and ultimately, how I can test this, and other endpoints.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Cheers,
C